# Method 'Copy' of object 'Sheets' failed

Tags: vba, excel, copy, excel-2013

After reinstalling Office 2013 I got this error:

> Run-time error '-21474178848 (80010108)':
>   Method 'Copy' of object 'Sheets' failed

In this the code block:

```
Set ThisWork = ActiveWorkbook
    strExt = ThisWork.Sheets("Catalog1").Cells(2, 4).Value & "_" & Format(Now, "yyyy_mm_dd_hhmmss")
    strSaveName = ThisWork.Path & "\" & strExt & ".xlsx"

    ThisWork.Sheets(Array("Catalog1", "Catalog2", "Translations")).Copy
    With ActiveWorkbook
...
```

After pressing debug and pressing Continue (<kbd>F5</kbd>), Excel crashes.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Do you actually have sheets `Catalog2` and `Translations` on your workbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Sheets names in VBA Windows

In your case it probable wrong names in (name) section which depends on Excel localization. try to change (name) value which you have probably sheet1 or sheet2 and change it to Catalog1 or Catalog2 so whey must much name section.

So now you may have

```
Sheet1 (Catalog1)
Sheet2 (Catalog2)
```

You must rename to

```
Catalog1 (Catalog1)
Catalog2 (Catalog2)
```

Comment: Yes this is solve my problem as i have different language of my Office and (name) section will be Sheet2 (Catalog1), Лист1 (Catalog2) , after change them to Catalog1 (Catalog1), Catalog2 (Catalog2) everething works fine. thanks