# .copy working inconsistently while copying current workbook to new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have code extracting lots of information from other workbooks into the master workbook in several sheets. At the end I want to save the master workbook as xlsx (macro free) and delete shapes and button from that xlsx sheets.

Below code sometime works but strangely sometime without creating copy it delete buttons/shapes from the master book itself or hit error: Method 'Copy' of object 'Sheets' failed:

```
Sub SaveFileInXlsFormat()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim fName As String
Dim fPath As String
 ' Copy worksheets to a new workbook

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Array("week", "month", "year", "Q-1", "Q-2", "Q-3", "Prev Year")).Copy
```

Comment: Please show the full function or provide a full [mcve]. To find out which sheet is the issue please try to copy them one by one (not using an array but a copy action for each, just for debugging). • Errors that only occur sometimes or process the wrong workbook or worksheet are most likely caused by using `ActiveSheet`, `ActiveWorkbook`, `.Select` or not using proper workbook and worksheet references (this incudes using implicit references to  `ActiveSheet`, `ActiveWorkbook` by not using workbook/worksheet references at all).

Comment: Also checkout this answer: [Method 'Copy' of object 'Sheets' failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34493808/method-copy-of-object-sheets-failed)

Comment: Thank you Peh, i'll properly declare workbook and worksheets.. thank you for your help, will share how i go with the changes and if any issue while making changes